# change the size of icon in BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android

I am forced to use `BottomNavigationView`, and I need to make its icons bigger, I changed their size, but the title of `BottomNavigationItemView` comes above the Image.

So, I need somehow to resize the size of icons, and make the title of `BottomNavigationItemView` under the image, which means resize `BottomNavigationView`, `BottomNavigationMenuView`.

Comment: Can you extend the BottomNav or are you forced to only work with it, as it comes?

Comment: Unfortunately, as it comes.

Comment: I tried to give the ImageView a margin or something, but the height of `BottomNavigationMenuView` does not able to change, so the title disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem, I would recommend you, overriding the height of the BottomNavigation:

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">64dp</dimen>
```

But this line of code inside a value resource file and you should be good to go!

Edit:

Sorry I missed, that you also requested, how to change the icon size, but this works similar:

```
<dimen name="bottom_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">32dp</dimen>
```

Whit these 2 dimension-overrides, you should be fine!

Comment: thanks a lot, I did not refresh the page, so I could not see your answer when I wrote  my answer below ,apologize me.
yes, your answer is right my friend and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by set the item icon size `bottomNavigationView.setItemIconSize(yourNewIconSize);`

but as I said, the title comes over the icon, so I should add this line `<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height">80dp</dimen>` into my `dimens.xml` file to increase the height of `bottomNavigationView`, and `80dp` is just an example value.